# Capacitor identification

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, electrolytic-capacitor

I am replacing a blown capacitor on my LCD monitor power supply board. While I have the thing in pieces I thought I would replace the other electrolytics as well as they may well fail in the future. However one of them is missing part of its value and I'm hoping that someone will be able to help identify it.

The capacitor is rated at 50v and the part of the value that is visible is possibly 8uF, however the characters before are missing (the plastic sleeve is damaged). Physically it is 10mm high, 5mm in diameter. It is part C824 on a Digital Decode Ltd P/N BLM1700P60411 board. It is adjacent to the 817c optocoupler.

As I said above it looks OK so if it can't be identified I'll just leave it and hope for the best.

[image]

Comment: A picture would be very helpful!

Comment: Possibly 68uF? That's the only standard capacitor that comes to mind with 8 at the end.

Comment: I've added a photo, not very good I'm afraid as my camera won't focus that closely.

Comment: Repair/shopping questions are off-topic!

Comment: @LeonHeller: Where's the ultimate decision that repair questions are off topic? It's ridiculous to ban these questions from EE. This question is a component identification question as well.

Comment: Mind our mobile Internet users: Please crop and scale your image to a more useful size. Also consider desoldering the cap, then take the picture.

Comment: Thus is not one of the caps you need to change. You only need to change the physically larger electrolytic ones. Those are the ones that fail.

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky: You don't really expect Leon to provide *reasoning* with his comments, do you? :)

Comment: once you get it desoldered you can test its value...

Comment: Yes, you posted a picture.  I guess Camil should have specified it be a *useful* one.  I can see how he thought that would be understood though.

Comment: @GradyPlayer: not if it's broken. "I'm replacing a *blown* capacitor".

Comment: A quick search shows that this particular board (also known as PI-SB02) is commonly used in many monitors, and is widely available as a complete assembly for $20-$30. You may want to just get a spare and be done with it.

Comment: @Johan.A that one isn't blown. OP said he's just replacing them all, after having replaced the already bad one.

Comment: @LeonHeller Hell, even then, it's not a repair question, OP already knows what he is doing. It's not a shopping question, i.e. "Where do I get this part". Strictly Identification. And Szymon gives a great example of not just what it might be, or how to find that out. Searching for a few fields narrows down the value alot.

Comment: @Madmanguruman How could you get that result with a quick search?! You are a guru, indeed :)

Comment: @abdullahkahraman Sometimes I get lucky. :)

Comment: @Madmanguruman I investigated getting a new board but I'm in the UK and they are not easily available here. Shipping one from the US is just too much trouble. I've ordered a replacement cap from Farnell which, hopefully will get it up and running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's 10µF (PI-SB02 REV1.3)

Photo:
[image: proof picture]

Comment: The whole question may be *off-topic→repair*.  But I don't see the reason for -1 to this answer.

Comment: @Nick: I don't either. +1

Comment: Cripes, what a way to repay this kind of good work. +1 from me too.

Answer (score 4):

Quick look in Farnell for 50V, 5mm diameter, radial leaded cap gives only three possible values: 0.68, 6.8 and 18µF. 5mm diameter caps end at 33µF so I doubt it is a 68µF.

Comment: I assumed that it'd be a large capacitor, to 68uF seemed good, but it can be a multiple of 10 of course.